# How do I set these docker-compose ports in a kubernetes yaml file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

Given the following ports defined in a `docker-compose.yml` file, how do I do the equivalent in a kubernetes yml file?

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
  seq.logging:
    image: datalust/seq
    networks: 
      - backend
    container_name: seq.logging
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5300:80" # UI
      - "5301:5341" # Data ingest
```

#### `kubernetes.yml`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backend-infrastructure
  labels:
    system: backend
    app: infrastructure
spec:

  containers:

  - name: seq-logging
    image: datalust/seq
#    ports: ?????????????????????????????????????
#    - containerPort: "5300:80" # UI
#    - containerPort: "5301:5341" # Data ingest
    env:
    - name: ACCEPT_EULA
      value: "Y"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not expose a port using Pod/deployment yaml. 
Services are the way to do it. Here you can either use multiple services on top of your pod/deployment but this will result in multiple IP addresses. Other way is to name each port and then create a multi port service definition.

In your case it should look somewhat like this (note this is just a quickly written example). [Also](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services)

> When using multiple ports you must give all of your ports names, so
>   that endpoints can be disambiguated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backend-infrastructure
  labels:
    system: backend
    app: infrastructure
spec:
  containers:
  - name: seq-logging
    image: datalust/seq
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80 # UI
      name: ui
    - containerPort: 5341 # Data ingest
      name: data-ingest
    env:
    - name: ACCEPT_EULA
      value: "Y"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: seq-logging-service
spec:
  type: #service type
  ports:
  - name: ui
    port: 5300
    targetPort: 80
  - name: data-ingest
    port: 5301
    targetPort: 5341
```

Some more resources:
- Docs about [connecting applications with services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#the-kubernetes-model-for-connecting-containers).
- example [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/nginx-secure-app.yaml) from the above featuring deployment with multiple port container and corresponding service.

Update:
[containerPort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#containerport-v1-core)

> List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives
>   the system additional information about the network connections a
>   container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port
>   here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is
>   listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be
>   accessible from the network. Cannot be updated.

Comment: thank you kindly for your help. I have a quick question - by default, the Seq-logging image (which I didn't make) has (internally) `port 80` for UI and `port 5341` for data-ingest. Doesn't this mean that with the pod/deployment section above, the `containerPort` should be `containerPort: 80` and `containerPort: 5341`? if "yes" does this mean the service `port/targetPort` remain the same? Maybe I misunderstood the definition of pod->`containerPort`.

Comment: yes, in this case I made a mistake (I thought  the app ports are 5300 and 5301). I will edit the yaml accordingly.